# Modified exponential summation

Tags: binomial-theorem, exponential-sum

How do we prove that
$$1+\frac{2^3}{2!}+\frac{3^3}{3!}+\frac{4^3}{4!}+\cdots=5e$$

I'll post the answer to this question as a knowledge share.

Comment: Yeah kinda...I've posted the answer myself as a knowledge share though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S$ denote the sum in question.

$$S=\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{r^3}{r!}\right)$$

Here, the general term
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
t_r &= \frac{r^3}{r!}\\
&=\frac{r^2}{(r-1)!}\\
&=\frac{(r-1+1)^2}{(r-1)!}\\
&=\frac{(r-1)^2}{(r-1)!}+\frac{1}{(r-1)!}+\frac{2(r-1)}{(r-1)!}\\
&=\frac{r-1}{(r-2)!}+\frac{1}{(r-1)!}+\frac{2}{(r-2)!}\\
&=\frac{r-2+1}{(r-2)!}+\frac{1}{(r-1)!}+\frac{2}{(r-2)!}\\
&=\frac{r-2}{(r-2)!}+\frac{1}{(r-2)!}+\frac{1}{(r-1)!}+\frac{2}{(r-2)!}\\
&=\frac{1}{(r-3)!}+\frac{3}{(r-2)!}+\frac{1}{(r-1)!}\\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Splitting $S$ to my convenience, I’ll write:

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
S&=1+\frac{2^3}{2!}+\sum\limits_{r=3}^{\infty}\left(\frac{r^3}{r!}\right)\\
&=1+\frac{2^3}{2!}+\sum\limits_{r=3}^{\infty}\left\{\frac{1}{(r-3)!}+\frac{3}{(r-2)!}+\frac{1}{(r-1)!}\right\}\\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

From the exponential series, we have

$$e^x=\sum\limits_{r=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x^r}{r!}\right)$$
$$\implies e=\sum\limits_{r=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{r!}\right)$$

Utilizing this result, we can write,

$$
S=\left(1+\frac{2^3}{2!}\right)+e+(3e-3)+(e-2)=5e
$$